# Do resource bundles in Java support runtime string substitution?

Tags: java, resourcebundle

Can you do the following with a Java ResourceBundle?

In the properties file...

```
example.dynamicresource=You currently have {0} accounts.
```

At runtime...

```
int accountAcount = 3;
bundle.get("example.dynamicresource",accountCount,param2,...);
```

To give a result of

"You currently have 3 accounts."

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Not without using the [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) class, such as:

```
String pattern = bundle.getString("example.dynamicresource");
String message = MessageFormat.format(pattern, accountCount);
```

Comment: While this works, it is not necessarily "Yes" that ResourceBundle can do this.  ResourceBundle does not have a mechanism.

Answer (score 11):

On their own, `ResourceBundle` does not support property placeholders. The usual idea is to take the String you get from the bundle, and stick it into a `MessageFormat`, and then use that to get your parameterized message.

If you're using **JSP/JSTL**, then you can combine `<fmt:message>` and `<fmt:param>` to do this, which uses `ResourceBundle` and `MessageFormat` under the covers.

If you happen to be using **Spring**, then it has the `ResourceBundleMessageSource` which [does something similar](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-messagesource), and can be used anywhere in your program. This `MessageSource` abstraction (combined with `MessageSourceAccessor`) is much nicer to use than `ResourceBundle`.

Answer (score 6):

There are various ways, depending on the view technology you're using. If you're using "plain vanilla" Java (e.g. Swing), then use [`MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) API as answered before. If you're using a webapplication framework (which is true, if I judge your question history here correctly), then the way depends on the view technology and/or MVC framework you're using. If it is for example "plain vanilla" JSP, then you can use JSTL [`fmt:message`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/message.html) for this.

```
<fmt:message key="example.dynamicresource">
    <fmt:param value="${bean.accountCount}">
</fmt:message>
```

If it is for example JSF, you can use [`h:outputFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputFormat.html) for this.

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{bundle['example.dynamicresource']}">
    <f:param value="#{bean.accountCount}">
</h:outputFormat>
```

Best place is to just consult the documentation of the technology/framework you're using (or to tell it here so that we can give better suited and more detailed answers).

Answer (score 3):

Struts have a nice util called `MessageResources` which does exactly what you ask for....

e.g.

```
MessageResources resources = getResources(request, "my_resource_bundle"); // Call your bundle exactly like ResourceBundle.getBundle() method
resources.getMessage("example.dynamicresource",accountCount,param2,...);
```

**Limitation**
It only allows maximum of 3 parameters (i.e. resource attribute, param1, ..., param3).

I suggest using **MessageFormat** (if you want to use more than 3 parameter values) as suggested by David Sykes.

**PS** the `getResources` method is available only in the Struts `Action` class.

Comment: **As a note/update**:  The Struts 1.x web framework has reached its [end of life](http://struts.apache.org/struts1eol-press.html) and is no longer officially supported since May 2013.

Comment: **As an addition**: Struts 2 provides a better alternative in the form of *getText()* methods. Those methods are defined in the [*TextProvider*](http://struts.apache.org/maven/xwork-core/apidocs/index.html?com/opensymphony/xwork2/TextProvider.html) interface, which *ActionSupport* class implements. There are two *getText()* methods that support message parameter substitution: one that takes an array and one that takes a list, and both do not have any (reasonable) limitations on the number of parameters.

Comment: @informatik01 though your answer is valid at this moment, this answer was posted in March 2010, when Struts 1.x was *still* supported.

Comment: I know, that's why I marked the first comment as an **update**. And I was not trying to compromise your answer, it's just a *note for others who are not aware of those changes*. No offense :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can make this work for Non-English properties file.

My message.properties file has the following line:

**info.fomat.log.message.start=Starting to parse log message in {0} format.**

And my message_fr_FR.properties file has the following line:

**info.fomat.log.message.start=A partir d'analyser le message connecter {0} format.**

This code works only for the English one

**String.format((String) messages   .getString(GlobalConstants.MESSAGE_FORMAT_START), GlobalConstants.STR_JSON));**

It does **NOT** replace the placeholder with the value when my language / locale is French :-(

Even MessageFormat.fomat() is no good

Comment: When using String.format(..) you can use classical C format format specifiers like '%d', '%s'.

Comment: MRay: It seems that the single quote in your French text may be the problem according to the answer by @tleveque. What happens When you change your string to info.fomat.log.message.start=A partir d''analyser le message connecter {0} format.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe ResourceBundle can do that itself, but String can:

```
String.format(bundle.getString("example.dynamicresource"), accountCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that when using `MessageFormat.format()` you need to use a double quote (`''`) in your resource bundle if you want to express single quote (`'`).

Answer (score 0):

[MessageFormoat#format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) will work for the case like:

```
greetingTo=Have Param, saying hello {0}
```

You can declare two methods like this where RB is a instance of ResourceBundle:

```
/**This is a method that takes the param to substitute the placeholder**/
public String getString(String key, Object... params  ) {
    try {
        return MessageFormat.format(this.RB.getString(key), params);
    } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
        return "[" + key + "]";
    }
}

/**Without a param, this will derectly delegate to ResourceBundle#getString**/
public String getString(String key) {
    try {
        return this.RB.getString(key);
    } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
        return "[" + key + "]";
    }
}
```