# adding second level data in properties file

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, properties

What I have is properties file as below.

### welcome.properties

```
admin = Admin
welcomeAdmin = Welcome Admin
editAdmin = Edit Admin
```

as I have **repeated Admin** word, I want to use something like below.

```
admin = Admin
welcomeAdmin = Welcome #{admin}
editAdmin = Edit #{admin}
```

so that if I change at one place i.e. at `admin = Admin`, all places it will reflect.

Any idea/ suggestion how to get this done would be appreciated.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this works out of the box with Spring.

Comment: I am using JSF and there I am using it.

Comment: Then the property placeholder should do the trick: http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/8309

Comment: @JanGoyvaerts : I am using properties files in my JSF 2.0 project, but  need to know how can I use earlier data in below lines.

Answer (score 0):

As per today, classic `ResourceBundle` class doesn't support named parameters and their substitution, but rather supports simple placeholders of `{0}` type in your key-value pairs of your bundles, that would be substituted by using `MessageFormat#format`.

In this light if you replace `Welcome #{admin}` by `Welcome {0}` you'd be able to achieve the functionality you seek by using one of  the following:

1. *JSF's `<h:outputFormat>`*:

   ```
   <h:outputFormat value="#{msg.welcomeAdmin}">
       <f:param value="#{msg.admin}" />
   </h:outputFormat>
   ```
2. *JSTL's `<fmt:message>`*:

   ```
   <fmt:message key="msg.welcomeAdmin">
       <fmt:param value="#{msg.admin}">
   </fmt:message>
   ```

You could as well create your own EL function, or tag handler, or UI component, or make use of `MessageFormat` class methods in your beans, etc. Of course, you also could extend `ResourceBundle` class to support named parameters and return a message with named parameters already parsed.

**Suggested reading**:

1. [Do resource bundles in Java support runtime string substitution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451049/do-resource-bundles-in-java-support-runtime-string-substitution);
2. [How to use Parameterized MessageFormat with non-Value attributes of JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000006/how-to-use-parameterized-messageformat-with-non-value-attributes-of-jsf-componen);
3. [Pass parameters to messages from resource bundle to components other than h:outputFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697189/pass-parameters-to-messages-from-resource-bundle-to-components-other-than-hou).